# Animated icon inside input

Tags: animation, cakephp-3.0, font-awesome

How can I add a font awsome animated icon ( like **fa fa-reload fa-spin**) inside an input using **$this->form->input(code)**

```
<div class="input-wrapper"> 
    <input id="stuff"> 
    <label id ="spin" for="stuff" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin input-icon">
    </label> 
</div>
```

and for css

```
.input-icon{ position: relative; right: 20px; } 
input{ padding-right: 20px; } 
.input-wrapper{ position: relative; }
```

Comment: you mean inside the input label

Comment: No, I want it inside the "text box"

Comment: You can put a font-awesome symbol inside your input but I don't think you can make it spin

Comment: I did it with html and css, but I Have no idea how to use the helper

Comment: post the html you want to obtain and your trials so far.

Comment: `<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="stuff">
  <label id ="spin" for="stuff" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin input-icon"></label>
</div>` and for css `.input-icon{
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
}
input{
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.input-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}`

Comment: you are not putting the icon inside the input. You're putting it inside the label and superimposing the label to the input via css

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you're trying to do it's right from a css point of view

Don't even know if it is the right way to use fontAwesome (You're applying the `fa` classes to the label instead o using in a `<i>` as usually done)

So I'm just going to show you how to replicate your exact html using cakephp

if you want to do using just one command you have to leverage on templates. You can change the form templates just for one form, for your whole application or just for a single control.

In my exhample I'm changing the templates just for this control

```
echo $this->form->control(
    'my_input_name', 
    [
        'label' => [
            'text' => '',
            'id' => 'spin',
            'class' => "fa fa-spinner fa-spin input-icon"
        ],
        'templates' => [
            'inputContainer' => '<div class="input-wrapper">{{content}}</div>',
            'formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}',

        ]
    ]
)
```